# what is the query to create alert in grafana if there is increment in the error count

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, grafana, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

Have integrated prometheus with my springboot application, and using micrometer I am counting the exceptions occur in the application then adding to prometheus as shown below:

```
public Sample(MeterRegistry registry) {

        error_count = Counter
                .builder("error_count")
                .description("error processing ").register(registry);

    }

   testMethod(){

       try{
         }

      catch(Exception ex){
             error_count.increment();

         }
}
```

have integrated prometheus with grafana and reading the exception count in grafana dashboard.
If there is any increment in the exception count how can we raise an alert in grafana, what is the condition we need to specify in alert section to check when the new exception is raised.

Comment: Checkout this project;s source code https://github.com/in4it/prometheus-course/tree/master/spring-boot-prometheus

Answer (score 0):

Calculate error rate from your error counter metric by using Prometheus rate function. Then alert condition is easy: alert if error rate is more than zero.

Comment: Hi @Jan Garaj, thankyou very much for your response, could not find rate function at alert section in grafana. Have specified rate(error_count[5m]) in Query. What we need to specify as a alert condition